# Reparenting a console host window has rendering issues

Tags: c, winapi, console

I reparented the console window retrieved by *AllocConsole()* to a window owned by a different process using the following code:

```c
SetParent(console, main_window_handle);
SetWindowLongPtr(console, GWL_STYLE, WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD);

SetWindowPos(console, HWND_TOP, 10, 20, CONSOLE_WINDOW_WIDTH, CONSOLE_WINDOW_HEIGHT, SWP_FRAMECHANGED);
```

That works so far, but rendering turns out to have unexpected results:

[image]

The rendering is fixed once I move the new parent window to another display and back.

What is causing this issue?

Comment: Using SetParent on a window that you don't own (ie: wrote the code) is basically a hack, the parented window isn't expecting this, so, anything can happen, now and in the future with newer versions of that window.

Comment: [Is it legal to have a cross-process parent/child or owner/owned window relationship?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130412-00/?p=4683). And just because folks *love* to read *"Yes, of course!"* into the text, here's the TL;DR: No, you can't, so don't. The *problem* you are trying to solve has a solution. The solution you are trying to shoehorn onto your problem isn't part of the solution.

Comment: Thank you. So I need to create the console window by myself and not by using *AllocConsole()*.

Comment: No. You need to create a window that renders the console output, create a command processor process, and pipe its output into your (custom) output window.